# Truncate string excluding HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to truncate a word to 50 characters but in 50 characters it should not be an HTML tag. Suppose I have the below HTML:

```
<p>This is a test message</p>This is a test message<p>This is a test <a href="#">message</a> </p>
```

Then it should count 50 characters including only "This is a test message This is a test message This is a test message"

And after truncating, it should display like the below:

```
<p>This is a test message</p>This is a test message<p>This</p>
```

This I want to achieve using jQuery.

***EDIT***:
Sorry, adding one more condition:

I want to display till the last dot but it should not be more than 50 characters like the below:

```
<p>This is a test message</p>This is a test message.<p>This is a test <a href="#">message.</a> </p>
```

Then the output will be

```
<p>This is a test message</p>This is a test message.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need jQuery for this. A quick solution would be to loop over every character. If the character is inside `<` or `>` characters, then add it to the final string. Otherwise, only add it if the count of characters already added that were outside `<` or `>`s is less than 50:

```js
function shorten(s, maxChars) {
  let short = '';
  let tagFlag = false;
  let i = 0;
  for (const ch of s) {
    if (ch == '>' || ch == '<') {
      tagFlag = !tagFlag;
      short += ch;
    } else if (tagFlag) {
      short += ch;
    } else if (i < maxChars) {
      short += ch;
      i++;
    }
  }
  return short;
}

console.log(shorten('<p>This is a test message</p>This is a test message<p>This is a test <a href="#">message</a> </p>', 50));
```

The only pitfall of this is that tags like the `<a>` are still included, however, they are empty. Because the extra tags are empty, they won't show up and it shouldn't make a difference.

Per your update, you could keep the text in a temporary variable until you reach a dot, then only fully add that text once the dot is reached. This will throw out any extra text after the last dot. Then, you go through what was thrown out and add back in only the tags to make sure the result isn't missing any closing tags. Expand the snippet below to see this.

```js
function shorten(s, maxChars) {
  let short = '';
  let temp = '';
  let tagFlag = false;
  let i = 0;
  for (const ch of s) {
    if (ch == '>' || ch == '<') {
      tagFlag = !tagFlag;
      temp += ch;
    } else if (ch == '.' && i < maxChars) {
      short += temp + '.';
      temp = '';
    } else if (tagFlag) {
      temp += ch;
    } else if (i < maxChars) {
      temp += ch;
      i++;
    }
  }
  
  tagFlag = false;
  for (const ch of temp) {
    if (ch == '>' || ch == '<') {
      tagFlag = !tagFlag;
      short += ch;
    } else if (tagFlag) {
      short += ch;
    }
  }
  return short;
}

console.log(shorten('<p>This is a test message</p><p>This is a test message.<p>This is a test <a href="#">message.</a> </p></p>', 50));
```

Comment: @SwatiGupta Always happy to help! I've just edited my answer to include an extra snippet that accomplishes your extra condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my quick solution, you may need to adjust the output format, but this is how you can achieve using jQuery.

```
var html = '<p>This is a test message</p>This is a test message<p>This is a test <a href="#">message</a> </p>';


// strip HTML tags
var text = $(html).text(); 

// truncate to 50 characters
var truncated = text.substring(0, 50); 

// create a copy of the HTML
var result = $(html).clone().html(truncated);  with the truncated text

if (truncated.length < text.length) { 
  result.append('...');
}
console.log(result.prop('outerHTML'));
```

Console output:

```
"&lt;p&gt;This is a test messageThis is a test messageThis i...&lt;/p&gt;"
```

Comment: Thanks, Bryce for answer but I want output like this <p>This is a test message</p>This is a test message<p>This</p>

Comment: I think @Michael M. answer make sense to me if jQuery is not a must.